# Jquery UI - Box displaying value instead of label

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui

When I select the drop down it does not display the label, but rather the value. How do I get this to work properly? Here is my code:

```
            $("#mainIngredientAutoComplete").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "../api/IngredientChoices",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (v, i) {
                                var text = v.MainName;
                                if (text && (!request.term || matcher.test(text))) {
                                    return {
                                        label: v.MainName,
                                        value: v.MainItemID
                                    };
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#mainIngredientID").val(ui.item.value);
                    $("#mainIngredientAutoComplete").val(ui.item.label);
                }
            });
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771798/jquery-ui-autocomplete-how-to-select-an-item-and-mantain-the-label-not-the-va

Comment: @RachelGallen - I saw this post already. I am still not sure why my code is not working properly. To clarify, my MainINgredientID gets set properly, but my MainIngredientAutoComplete does not get overridden with the label value.

Comment: I ended up going another route, but I wonder if my issue was that the value referenced v.MainItemID instead of i.MainItemID.